# Group by and take mean of first three dates in the month?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a weekly dataframe that I need to merge with a monthly dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Date            Value
2020-01-01       2
2020-01-08       2
2020-01-16       2
2020-01-24       1
2020-02-01       1
2020-02-08       1
2020-02-16       1
2020-02-24       1
```

and I want to groupby the Date to merge with the other dataframe but only take the mean of the first three dates in that month (without assuming that the days would be the same for every month). How could I do this?

Thank you

Comment: do you mean take the first 3 entries of each unique month and average the values? because the spacing is not necessarily 1 day

Comment: @DerekEden yes the first 3 entries of each unique month, so for Jan/2020 you would take the mean of Jan 1st, 8th  and 16th and ignore the last one (24th)

Answer (score 3):

There is a more elegant solution, but this is how to break down the problem into small pieces to get you to solve this. Most answers can break these three steps in a single line of code.

```
# first group by month
df['date_trunc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('M')

# make a row number
df['row_number'] = df.groupby('date_trunc').cumcount()+1

         Date  Value date_trunc  row_number
0  2020-01-01      2    2020-01           1
1  2020-01-08      2    2020-01           2
2  2020-01-16      2    2020-01           3
3  2020-01-24      1    2020-01           4
4  2020-02-01      1    2020-02           1
5  2020-02-08      1    2020-02           2
6  2020-02-16      1    2020-02           3
7  2020-02-24      1    2020-02           4

# then filter to only values 3 or below and groupby the date_trunc and take the mean!
df.loc[df['row_number']<=3].groupby('date_trunc').mean()['Value']

date_trunc
2020-01    2
2020-02    1
```

Comment: Why `cumcount()+1`? If you just use `cumcount()` then you can use `df['row_number']=3`

Comment: @Dan, I think you mean `<3` but you are absolutely correct. `cumcount()+1` is a habit of mine since it's similar to SQL `row_number()` in how it behaves

Answer (score 1):

create a year_month only column, group by it and apply func to get mean of first 3:

```
df['YM'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('YM').apply(lambda x: x['Value'].iloc[:3].mean()))
```

Answer (score 1):

could also do this, simialr to Ezer K's:

```
df['grouper'] = df['Date'].str.extract('(\d{4}-\d{2})')
df.groupby('grouper')['Value'].apply(lambda x: sum(x[:3])/3)
```

output:

```
grouper
2020-01    2.0
2020-02    1.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: this assumes the dates are strings, and in YYYY-MM-DD format

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Andrej Kesely deleted their answer but It think it was on track to be the cleanest:

```
df["month_key"] = df["Date"].dt.to_period("M")
df.groupby("month_key").head(3).groupby("month_key").mean()
```

results in

```
           Value
month_key       
2020-01        2
2020-02        1
```

Comment: as a note this assumes the dates are datetimes

Comment: And if they are not I recommend casting them: `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`

Comment: I agree . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

You could just resample and take the mean of the 3 first values:

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('MS').agg(lambda x: x.iloc[:3].mean())
```

It gives:

```
            Value
Date             
2020-01-01      2
2020-02-01      1
```

You can `reset_index` if you want to get back the date column:

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('MS').agg(lambda x: x.iloc[:3].mean()).reset_index()
```

to have:

```
        Date  Value
0 2020-01-01      2
1 2020-02-01      1
```